# Wrong data stored in SFP module EEPROM?

Tags: eeprom, fibers

I want to distinguish several 1G SFP modules are copper or fiber. So I read the data from the EEPROM with ethtool. And I think the 'connector type' would be the most crucial info for me to achieve the goal.

Three fiber ones' connector type are all 0x01(SC). Good start.
But the 3 copper ones various. One is 0x22(Rj45), one is 0x07(LC) and one is 0x00(Unknow).
The most confusing one is this one "one is 0x07(LC)". It's a copper SFP with RJ45 connector, but the config stored in EEPROM shows it's a fiber SFP module.

I started handle this feature these days and I am not quite familiar with the industry standard. Also I am not sure if it's wrong configured because it's produced by a kind of big company...

I don't have too many modules to test. I hope to find a reliable way to distinguish the two different types.